# Pthread_cond_wait in C

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

#### Problem

Edit: As pointed out in the comments I made a mistake with `pthread_cond_wait` which caused it to never exit the thread.

I am working on a multi-threading assignment in C where I need to use multiple threads to sort a **4x4** array with **shearsort**, but I can't get that far because <strike>whenever I use `pthread_join`, the application never ends and it never joins.  The application just stays where it is until I control C to end it.</strike> I messed up my `pthread_cond_wait` meaning some of the threads would never continue.

I guess I'm asking how I should use `pthread_wait_cond`, because when I have both sides of the if/else statement have the `pthread_wait_cond` it doesn't output anything and just gets stuck.

Also, this is now part of the main issue, but I have seen many people start pthreads in a for loop, but when I tried that the I variable passed into the function seemed to be set at random, sometimes being correct with each thread getting its own number, but sometimes the threads would be created with the same number.  Would I need to use a mutex of some kind to ensure the `pthread_create` happens atomically and how should I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 4

void intSwap(int *a, int *b);
void *shearSort(void *rowCol);


pthread_cond_t sort0  =  PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t sort1  =  PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t sort2  =  PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t sort3  =  PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

pthread_cond_t writeArray  =  PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int array[N][N];

pthread_t thread[N];

void *shearSort(void *rowCol) {
  int x = 0, y = 0;
  printf("rowCol = %d", ((int)*(int*)rowCol));
  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

  if (((int)*(int*)rowCol)%2 == 0) {
    for(x = 0; x < N-1; x++) {
      for (y = 0; y < N-x-1; y++) {

        //pthread_cond_wait(&writeArray, &lock);
        if (array[((int)*(int*)rowCol)][y] > array[((int)*(int*)rowCol)][y+1]) {
          printf("rowCol = %d, i = %d, j = %d Swapping %d & %d\n", ((int)*(int*)rowCol), x, y, array[((int)*(int*)rowCol)][y], array[((int)*(int*)rowCol)][y+1]);
          intSwap(&array[((int)*(int*)rowCol)][y], &array[((int)*(int*)rowCol)][y+1]);
        }
        //pthread_cond_signal(&writeArray);

      }
    }
  }
  else {
    for(x = 0; x < N-1; x++) {
      for (y = 0; y < N-x-1; y++) {

        //pthread_cond_wait(&writeArray, &lock);
        if (array[((int)*(int*)rowCol)][y] < array[((int)*(int*)rowCol)][y+1]) {
          printf("rowCol = %d, i = %d, j = %d Swapping %d & %d\n", ((int)*(int*)rowCol), x, y, array[((int)*(int*)rowCol)][y], array[((int)*(int*)rowCol)][y+1]);
          intSwap(&array[((int)*(int*)rowCol)][y], &array[((int)*(int*)rowCol)][y+1]);
        }
        //pthread_cond_signal(&writeArray);

      }
    }
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  if(((int)*(int*)rowCol) == 1) {
    //pthread_join(thread[0], NULL);
  }
  if(((int)*(int*)rowCol) == 2) {
    //pthread_join(thread[0], NULL);
    //pthread_join(thread[1], NULL);
  }
  if(((int)*(int*)rowCol) == 3) {
    //pthread_join(thread[0], NULL);
    //pthread_join(thread[1], NULL);
    //pthread_join(thread[2], NULL);
  }

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void intSwap(int *a, int *b) {
  int temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}

int main () {

  FILE *input;

  int i = 0, j = 0;

  input = fopen("input.txt" , "r");

  if (input != NULL) {
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {

      for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        fscanf(input, "%d, ", &array[i][j]);
        printf("%d, ", array[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  else {
    perror( "There's a problem with the input.txt file, it doesn't seem to be there.");
exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }

  // for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, shearSort, (void *)&i);
  // }

  // for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
  // }

  int num0 = 0, num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 3;
  pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, shearSort, (void *)&num0);
  pthread_create(&thread[1], NULL, shearSort, (void *)&num1);
  pthread_create(&thread[2], NULL, shearSort, (void *)&num2);
  pthread_create(&thread[3], NULL, shearSort, (void *)&num3);

  pthread_join(thread[num0], NULL);
  pthread_join(thread[1], NULL);
  pthread_join(thread[2], NULL);
  pthread_join(thread[3], NULL);


  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      printf("%d, ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
return 0
}
```

When I ran the above code without the comments on `pthread_cond_wait` in the else I got this output from the command line then it just stops.

[image: *CommandLineOutput*]

```
5, 3, 9, 10,
2, -3, 11, 8,
20, 17, 19, 30,
24, 21, -2, 16,

rowCol = 0rowCol = 0, i = 0, j = 0 Swapping 5 & 3
rowCol = 1rowCol = 2rowCol = 2, i = 0, j = 0 Swapping 20 & 17
rowCol = 2, i = 0, j = 1 Swapping 20 & 19
^C
```

Now when I run the code as is I get this output:

[image: Output]

```
5, 3, 9, 10,
2, -3, 11, 8,
20, 17, 19, 30,
24, 21, -2, 16,

rowCol = 0rowCol = 0, i = 0, j = 0 Swapping 5 & 3
rowCol = 1rowCol = 1, i = 0, j = 1 Swapping -3 & 11
rowCol = 1, i = 0, j = 2 Swapping -3 & 8
rowCol = 1, i = 1, j = 0 Swapping 2 & 11
rowCol = 1, i = 1, j = 1 Swapping 2 & 8
rowCol = 2rowCol = 2, i = 0, j = 0 Swapping 20 & 17
rowCol = 2, i = 0, j = 1 Swapping 20 & 19
rowCol = 3rowCol = 3, i = 0, j = 2 Swapping -2 & 16
3, 5, 9, 10,
11, 8, 2, -3,
17, 19, 20, 30,
24, 21, 16, -2,
```

Comment: Why are you using `num0` for the first index, but hard-code the other indexes? And there's simply no need for the `num0` to `num3` variables, use loops instead.

Comment: Oh sorry I only did that to see if it would make any difference then I forgot to change it back.  As for when I tried to use a loop I had a problem where sometimes two different threads would receive the same input value from i, which was also part of my question.

Comment: OT: regardless of what visual studio might allow, there are only two valid signatures for the function: `main()`  they are: `int main( void )`  and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   Notice that they all have a returned type of `int`, not `void`

Comment: in function: `main()` this statement: `return;`  should be: `return 0;`

Comment: I'm not using visual studio, I'm writing in Notepad++ and compiling on my school's pyrite server, but thank you for pointing that out, I changed it back to int, I don't remember why I switched it to void in the first place lol

Comment: OT: regarding: `return 0;`   1) when outputting an error message, output it to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error is from a c library function, also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred (to `stderr`)   An easy way to do this is to call the function: `perror()`  2) when exiting, due to an error, do not use: `return;  Rather use: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are from the `stdlib.h` header flie

Comment: in function: `shearSort()`  these statement: `if (((int)*(int*)rowCol)%2 == 0) 
    {
  return 0;` results in none of the rest of the code in the `if()` block will ever be executed.  I.E. the rest of the `if()` block is 'dead code'.

Comment: in function: `shearSort()` the proper way to exit that thread is not `return 0` but rather: `pthread_exit( NULL );`

Comment: OK I fixed the error exit, but what are you talking about with the return 0 after if rowColl%2 == 0?  I don't see that anywhere in my code

Comment: I did use pthread_exit(NULL), are you looking in the right spot?  I don't see a single return statement in shearSort()

Comment: a copy/paste error on my part, just ignore what I said about the unexpected 'return' statement

Comment: in function: `shearSort()`, in the `else` block of the first `if()` the call to `pthread_cond_wait()` will result in this thread (and all the other threads) blocking, forever.

Comment: OT: when calling `pthread_create()` always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `void *shearSort(void *rowCol) 
{`   Suggest something similar to: `void *shearSort( void *arg ) { int rowCol = *(int *)arg;

Comment: Oh cool I am dumb, I meant to comment out both of those, now it finishes running correctly, but it still waits forever with it on both sides so how am I supposed to do mutual exclusion on that section of code?

Answer (score 1):

Before call pthread_cond_wait, make sure other threads to wake up it, so before call pthread_cond_wait, it need to judge whether there are other threads use the `array`, need to wait if the `array` is used, otherwise directly operate it

see the function `acquireWriteArray` and `releaseWriteArray` implemented below

In pthread_create, you can pass the value directly, not pass the address:

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, shearSort, (void *)(long)i);
```

modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 4

void intSwap(int *a, int *b);
void *shearSort(void *rowCol);

pthread_cond_t writeArray  =  PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int array[N][N];
pthread_t thread[N];
volatile int writeBusy = 0;

void acquireWriteArray()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    while (writeBusy) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&writeArray, &lock);
    }
    writeBusy = 1;
}

void releaseWriteArray()
{
    writeBusy = 0;
    pthread_cond_signal(&writeArray);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

void *shearSort(void *rowCol)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int idx = (long)rowCol;
    printf("rowCol = %d.\n", idx);

    if (idx % 2 == 0) {
        for(x = 0; x < N - 1; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < N - x - 1; y++) {

                acquireWriteArray();
                if (array[idx][y] > array[idx][y + 1]) {
                    printf("rowCol = %d, i = %d, j = %d Swapping %d & %d\n",
                           idx, x, y, array[idx][y], array[idx][y + 1]);
                    intSwap(&array[idx][y], &array[idx][y + 1]);
                }
                releaseWriteArray();
            }
        }
    } else {
        for(x = 0; x < N - 1; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < N - x - 1; y++) {

                acquireWriteArray();
                if (array[idx][y] < array[idx][y + 1]) {
                    printf("rowCol = %d, i = %d, j = %d Swapping %d & %d\n",
                           idx, x, y, array[idx][y], array[idx][y + 1]);
                    intSwap(&array[idx][y], &array[idx][y + 1]);
                }
                releaseWriteArray();
            }
        }
    }
    return (void *)NULL;
}

void intSwap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main ()
{

    FILE *input;

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    input = fopen("input.txt" , "r");

    if (input != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {

            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                fscanf(input, "%d, ", &array[i][j]);
                printf("%d, ", array[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        perror( "There's a problem with the input.txt file, it doesn't seem to be there.");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, shearSort, (void *)(long)i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("%d, ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```